# Restar un numero una fecha en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Como puedo restar una variable de una fecha en Ruby on Rails,

ejemplo:

quiero restar una variable, que puede contener cualquier valor entre 1 y 7, que representan a los días, a una fecha especifica.

en algoritmo seria algo como esto:

```
días = 5
fecha = 20170602
fecha_resultado = fecha - días
```

**fecha_resultado** tendría el valor de: **`20170527`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes si utilizas el tipo `Date` que Ruby implementa para estos casos:

```
dias = 5
fecha = Date.new(2017,06,02)
fecha_resultado = fecha - 5
```

Esto claro está también te sirve para ActiveRecord

Comment: Justo lo que buscaba, gracias